# Expressjs Req.method TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I have an error while running a node express server:

**index.js.**

```
const
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');

const config = require('./config');

const app = express();

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const apiTodos = require('./api/todos');

// connection mongodb via mongoose;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/todoslist', { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/todos', apiTodos);

app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(app.get('appPath'))));

app.listen(config.port, (err) => {
    if (err) { return console.log('Error:', err); }
    console.log('Listening on port %d', config.port);
});
module.exports = app;
```

**./api/todos(point in index.js)**

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = express.Router();

const controller = require('./todos.controller');

let router = new Router();

router.get('/check', controller.check);

module.exports = router;
```

**todos.constroller**

```
const tasklist = require('./todos.model');

    let check = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            (req, res) => {
                tasklist.find({})
                .then(data => {
                    resolve(console.log(data));
                    // resolve(res.status(200).json({ doc: data }));
                })
                .then(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    // res.status(503).json({ msg: err });
                });
            }
        }, 300);
    });
    module.exports = check;
```

**Error message:**

> node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138
>         debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);
>                                        ^
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
> ```

I don't know what I did wrong, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 6hours on that i got the probleme;

the probleme is how i module.exports "constrollers";

**todos.controller**

***the wrong way:***

```
const tasklist = require('./todos.model');

    let check = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            (req, res) => {
                tasklist.find({})
                .then(data => {
                    resolve(console.log(data));
                    // resolve(res.status(200).json({ doc: data }));
                })
                .then(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    // res.status(503).json({ msg: err });
                });
            }
        }, 300);
    });
    module.exports = check;
```

***and the right way:***

```
const tasklist = require('./todos.model');
module.exports = {
  check: (req, res, next) => {
        tasklist.find({})
        .then(data => {
          if (data === null) {
            res.status(404).json({ errmsg: 'aucune Competences trouver' });
          } else {
            res.status(200).json({ errmsgok: 'cool', doc: data });
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }
};
```

**i should have export modules as json type, and promise is not a problem it's your chose
voilà**

**thx for all the help!!!**

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of mistakes in the way you have named your files. I see that you have named your model as todo.model and your controller as todo.controller. Are those file extensions? If so, they cannot be. Please rename your files as todo.js. You can put them into separate folders so you can keep your model and controller separate.

```
\models
  \todo.js //This can contain your models
\controllers
  \todo.js // This can contain your controllers.
```

you can reference them as

```
const todoController = require('../controllers/todo');
const todoModel = require('../models/todo');
```

Comment: This should most likely solve your problem, if it doesn't solve your problem then edit your question with the complete stack trace

Answer (score 0):

todos.constroller check method does not have a [request](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) and [response](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) objects as parameters, and it is not necessary to use timeouts or promises, you can change it to this:

**todos.constroller**

```
const tasklist = require('./todos.model');

module.exports = {
    check: (req, res, next) => {
      tasklist.find({})
      .then(data => {
          res(data);
      })
      .then(err => {
          console.log(err);
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was caused by splitting my files into separate modules and missing this one line

```
const app = express();
```

in the via "require" included file (in the base file which includes you have this also).

Maybe it helps.